# Cypher queries: How to show all the relationships to one specific category

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm working on an app which is a backend for a book store. Inside the neo4j app, I would like to write a query which will show me for one category all the books related to. Like if I have a fantasy I will see all books which have fantasy category. I tried to manipulate this 
`MATCH p=()-[r:HAS_CATEGORY]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25` But I do not succeed to see the results I need. I also would like to understand for example if I want to see more categories and book related to. I'm using the last Neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand things right you are starting from a given book and want to see all books in the same category ?

Something like :

```
MATCH p=(b:Book {id: "xxx"})-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(c:Category)<-[:HAS_CATEGORY]-(o:Book) WHERE o <> b
RETURN p
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you data model looks something like this:

```
(:Book)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(:Category {name: 'name-of-category'})
```

then here is a Cypher query to get all `Book` nodes with the "SciFi" `Category:

```
MATCH (b:Book)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(:Category {name: 'SciFi'})
RETURN b;
```

Comment: this is not giving me any result and I think I did something wrong with the GraphDB. Under relationship section, I see only 2 but no has_category. But the books I have have a category assigned to. So how to add that has a category?

Comment: I don't have any results writing your query using a category Horror as it is in my DB. I wrote this ` MATCH p=(:Book)-[r:HAS_CATEGORY]->(:Category{name: 'Horror'}) RETURN p LIMIT 25 `
But writing this ` MATCH p=()-[r:HAS_CATEGORY]->() RETURN p ` showing me all the categories and the books pointing to the category. What i'm writing wrong to see just one category with all the books related to?